# Assign hostname to IP without editing hosts file

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, hostname

I need to addhosts temporarily and multiple times to Windows and would like to be able to do so without having to constantly edit the `system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file, since the changes only need to last the length of the session at most.  I was hoping there is some sort of terminal command I could use (that works similar to `net use`) but for telling windows to map `<hostname>` to `<ip>`.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MS KB article regarding the [TCP/IP Host Name Resolution Order](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172218) provides the following order:

> 1. The client checks to see if the name queried is its own.
> 2. The client then searches a local Hosts file, a list of IP address and
>      names stored on the local computer.
> 3. Domain Name System (DNS) servers are queried.
> 4. If the name is still not resolved, NetBIOS name resolution
>      sequence is used as a backup.

It further states that:

> This order can be changed by
>   configuring the NetBIOS node type of
>   the client.

And provides some links on how to change that order. Basically, as I see it, there are only 2 real parameters you control here:

1. The hosts file
2. Providing your own DNS server

My suggestion is that you manipulate the hosts file through a simple script (it is, after all, a simple text file, with a permanent and known location).

Or, run a DNS service, configure it to be your primary one and serve the desired IP addresses from it.